# Javascript: setting option's selected attribute doesn't change it's selected property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid, multi-select

For some reason the **selected attribute of an option in my project doesn't affect it's selected property**, and I have no idea why.

I'm using **jqGrid's** column selector in order to select column's to display on my grid.
The column selector is based on **multiSelect.js** which uses a select to mark the selected columns for display.
The problem that multiSelect.js uses the `option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected')` to mark a column as selected, but checks selection with the `option.selected` property. Usually the 2 are identical, but not in this case.

For maintenance reasons I don't want to mess with the plugin's code, so if any one knows why the this happens I'd appreciate the help.

Thanks,
  Yuval

Comment: possible duplicate of [.prop() vs .attr()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? As @undefined states, it could be a .prop() vs .attr() issue.

Comment: It's a much later version, and also as you can see the code in discussion isn't jQuery, but pure java script. The highlighted code is a snippet taken from multiselect.js

Answer (score 0):

Read the blog post for when jQuery 1.6.1 was released we had a huge education issue revolving around attributes and properties.  I think this will explain what's happening to you.

http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/

Comment: As I commented above, the access is done by pure java-script and not with jQuery. Thanks though.

Comment: The point of posting the link was to point out the difference between attr and prop that jQuery was trying to solve.  That blog post has a great write up of the differences which I thought would help you understand what is happening.